# Android - How to POST data to server DB

Tags: android, parsing, client-server, http-post

In my app, there is a wishlist that users can add some wishlist item with name, note, and image from the phone. And I want to send these data to the server side of DB.
Format is below..

```
 {
  "post": {
    "product name": "somename",
    "note": "description of the product",
    "image": "http://localhost/someimage.jpg",
   },
 }
```

So my question is how can i form this JSON array and POST it to server DB...
and how to code php to receive the POST request from the client side?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Does the server backend have to be in PHP?

Comment: no! what could be the other options?

Comment: You can use Java and Google App Engine. In Eclipse you make a new "Google App Engine Connected Android App" and it will make the app and the server backend. Then you can add your entities on the server and generate the android client libraries from the IDE. It's RESTful and secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this class:

```
public class HttpClass
{
public static String postData(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

    String responseString = "";
    String responsemsg = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //String tempUrl = HungryPagesConfig.registrationAPI;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        // Log.e("Rsponse", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        Log.e("Rsponse", responseString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responseString;
}
}
```

Make post `()` in your `mainActivity`:

```
public void Fun()

{
JSONObject Json,Mainjson;
String Data;
try {
            Json.put("product name",  "somename");
            Json.put("note", "description of the product");
            Json.put("image","http://localhost/someimage.jpg");
            Mainjson.put("post",Json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Data = Mainjson.toString();
        Log.e("Rsponse", Data);

        PostData.nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         PostData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", Data));
}
```

Now call the `Fun()` function whatever you'd like your post to be successfully done.

Make another class, `PostData`:

```
public class PostData 
{

String url;
JSONObject add;
public HttpClass jParser = new HttpClass();
public void post()
{
tempUrl = HungryPagesConfig.AddMenuItemAdmin;
        try {
            add = new JSONObject(jParser.postData(url,
                    nameValuePairs));
            Log.e("Rsponse", add.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Im a far too beginner..so that i have a question. where should i make the http class and postdata class?..do i need to make other java file for that? i added fun in the main activity.

Comment: ya you have to create httpclass.java file and postdata.java file in any packge nd fun calling in your main activity.i dnt knw wher you want to post the data on button click or load.so uhav to jst call the fun whatever you like okk...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourwebsite.com.au/index.jsp");
String trackid= getTrackid();
List<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("columval1","123"));
namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("columval2","145"));
namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("columval3","445"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();
String origresponseText = EntityUtils.toString(rp);
String htmlTextStr = Html.fromHtml(origresponseText).toString();
pass=htmlTextStr.trim();
```

Comment: write where ever you need....example when you click a button if you want to insert some datas to the remote DB the write the same code within the button click action

Comment: and..i think i need to code json parser on the client side also..right?